# Need weird advice in how to allow a Linux process ONLY create and use a single pipe

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, pipe, restriction

Hoi.

I am working on an experiment allowing users to use 1% of my CPU. That's like your own Webserver; but a big dynamic remote execution framework (dont ask about that), and I dont want users to use API functions like create files, no sockets, no threads, no console output, nothing.

**Update1:** People will be sending me binaries, so `interrupt 0x80` is possible. Therefore... Kernel?

I need to limit a process so it cannot do anything but use a *single pipe*. Through that pipe the process will use my own wrapped and controlled API.

Is that even possible? I thought like a Linux kernel module.

The issues with limiting RAM and CPU are not primary here, for that there's something on google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you be compiling the programs, or will users be sending you binaries?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace).

Comment: You can use chroot to limit access to the rest of the file system. But to limit things like socket creation and whatnot, you'd probably have to roll your own libc or at least wrap libc/glibc to impose the limits.

Comment: @GregHewgill Can you write an answer about that? Looks what I want. Wikipedia states it can monitor what it **did**. Can it limit, too?

Comment: Ummm, maybe opening a pipe and then enabling seccomp?

Comment: @ninjalj Can you write an answer about that ? I'd immediately flag that as THE answer. That is exactly what I want. With that comes the memory limit, doesnt it ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) facility will allow your program to observe and control the operation of another process. Using the `PTRACE_SYSCALL` flag, you can stop the child process before *every* syscall, and make a decision about whether you want to allow that system call to proceed.

Comment: Do I have to check every damn instruction, or will it trigger automatically?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "damn instruction". There are many possible options to `ptrace()`, I recommend reading the documentation. There are options for single step as well as running until the next syscall.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at what Google is doing with their [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) technology and the seccomp sandbox.  The Native Client (NaCl) stuff is intended to let x86 binaries supplied by a web site run inside a user's local browser.  The problem of malicious binaries is similar to what you face, so most of the technology/research probably applies directly.